# I cannot install packages nodejs packages on docker?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am new on docker. I first build dockerfile after install get only error. This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM  node

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm i -g npm@latest
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

When run `docker build .` command I get this error:

```
=> ERROR [5/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                   150.9s 
------
 > [5/6] RUN npm install:
#9 43.89 npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
#9 73.65 npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
#9 88.65 npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
#9 149.2 npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
#9 149.2 npm ERR! network Socket timeout
#9 149.2 npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
#9 149.2 npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
#9 149.2 npm ERR! network
#9 149.2 npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
#9 149.2 npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
#9 149.3
#9 149.3 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#9 149.3 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-17T12_09_49_294Z-debug-0.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Dockerfile` that works for me

```
FROM node:18-bullseye

WORKDIR /node-app

COPY package-lock.json package.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . .
```

Your issue is to remove the quote from the `WORKDIR '/app'` when copying the `package-lock.json and package.json` they should be COPYed to `./`

The 3rd line `RUN npm ci`, is used to install packages that are in your `package-lock.json` file so you keep the same libraries as a BEST PRACTICE, `npm install` it may fetch some updates to some packages that you have, so as I mentioned, it's a best practice to use `npm ci` instead of `npm install`

Comment: This too get this error

Comment: Did you try to skip the `npm ci` part, and copy the whole project, so that you can confirm the error is due to it.